# The Problem with listing all remote branches with latest commit date in git bash

Tags: git, sh

I wanted to run this command line in my git bash, but I can not see any result.

My Goal is: Listing all remote branches with latest commit date.

the command looks like this

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format='%ci %cr' $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

my qustion is,
1: how to run sh command in git bash.
2: is here somthing wrong in this command? systex erro?

any solutions?

Comment: Like any other program you're trying to debug, break it down: does `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD` do what you expect? does `for branch in \`git branch -r | grep -v HEAD\`; do echo $branch; done` do what you expect? and so on

Comment: By the way, your first question doesn't make much sense, because git bash _is_ a shell, so you're asking "how to run git bash command in git bash", to which the answer is, type it in and press Enter.

Comment: Hi, yes, I want to list all remote branches and latest commit date.

Comment: git branch -r | grep -v HEAD this command was working, but I just want to more information about commit date also

Answer (score 2):

Clone a new repository for this task.

```
git clone <repo_url>
```

It's better to update all the remote tracking branches every time. But in your case, it depends.

```
git fetch origin -q +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin | grep -v 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD' | while read s t r;do
    echo $r $(git log -1 --pretty='%ci %cr' $s)
done
```

It can be simpler.

```
git fetch origin -q +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format="%(refname) %(committerdate:iso) %(committerdate:relative)"  | grep -v 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'
```

A shell script sample. Suppose the repository is at `/path/to/repo`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d /path/to/repo ]];then
    git clone --no-checkout <repo_url> -- /path/to/repo
fi

export GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git
git fetch origin -q +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format="%(refname) %(committerdate:iso) %(committerdate:relative)"  | grep -v 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'
unset GIT_DIR
```

Comment: Can I run this command also in Jenkins? I have tried, it was not working

Comment: @user1938143 I think it can work also in Jenkins. Do you use shell script in jenkins?

Comment: sh """
               test -d "./.git" && git fetch || git clone -n ${protocol}://$GITUSER:$GITPASSWD@${srcurl} .
               
               git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format="%(refname) %(committerdate)" | grep -v HEAD > .git/branchesList
          """

Comment: yes I use sh command in jenkins

Comment: @user1938143 I wrote a bash script demo. You could refer to it and see if it's okay.

Comment: I have also a question, can I set uotput date only with year, month and day?

Comment: @user1938143 Of course. Use `%(committerdate:short)` in the format string.

Comment: thanks, Can I get also the information about owner of a branch?

Comment: I got it with %(authorname)

Comment: @user1938143 No. A git branch does not have an owner. It does not belong to somebody. You may appoint someone as the owner or maintainer of a branch, but Git does not record such relationship. `%(authorname)` is not the owner. It's just the author of a commit. And you may want `%(committername)` who makes the commit.

Comment: Except for the fact that Jenkins tends to use shallow, single-branch clones, I'd ditch the arguments past `git fetch remote`. Even with Jenkins, I'd still ditch those, I'd just have the script start by making sure it's not a single-branch clone. :-) But both approaches should work.